# Recursion in the main function

Tags: c++, recursion, program-entry-point

I tried recursion in the main function, but why 'i' variable is not getting updated, it only gets updated till i=1 and then remains constant.
Below is the code:-

```
int main(int i = 0)
{
    std::cout << "i value" << i << std::endl;
    if (i == 3)
        return 0;
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    main(i++);
}
```

Comment: Were you asking about C, as opposed to C++, then I would be inclined to think that you have mischaracterized the behavior: in the code presented, every execution of `main()` should see the value 0 for `i`.  None should see 1.  This is because each execution of a function has its own copies of its local variables, and your recursive call to `main()` passes the value `i` has *before* it is incremented.  Of course, that's kinda speculative, because the signature you have given for `main` is not valid in C, even if we ignore the default value for `i`.

Comment: The C++ standard disallows use of `main()` - it is not possible to take its address, nor is it possible for it to be called recursively.

Comment: ***Why*** do you want to call the `main` function in such a way? Why not simply create a second function which does as you want without risking breaking things and running into UB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See for example [cppreference/main_function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function):

> The main function has several special properties:
>
> 1. It cannot be used anywhere in the program
>
>    a) in particular, **it cannot be called recursively**
>
>    b) its address cannot be taken
>
> [...]

You cannot call `main` recursively. Also your signature is not correct. Correct signatures are:

```
int main () { body }                                                (1)     
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { body }                          (2)     
/* another implementation-defined form, with int as return type */  (3)
```

For (3) you need to check your implementation, I am not aware of one that allows `int main(int)` (though I didn't bother to check).

Last but not least, `foo(i++);` will increment `i` and then call `foo` with the original value of `i`. You probably want `foo(++i);` or rather `foo(i + 1);`.

TL;DR

```
int my_main(int i=0) {
     // put code here
     my_main(i + 1);
}

int main() {
   my_main();
}
```

Comment: @JohnBollinger realized that just some seconds ago and addressed it with the last edit. I always wonder where that `++` fetish is coming from. Whats wrong with writing `my_main(i + 1)`? Imho thats the only correct way when `i` will not be used afterwards

Comment: That fetish comes from the basic mindset burned into new-to-C tutorials from inception. You want one-greater than some integer, this is how you do it: a nifty little operator. The *context* of whether you actually want *the variable* to be one greater vs. simply acquire a value one-greater is glossed over and often never considered, especially when learning recursion.

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: @WhozCraig I still remember a prof of mine answering "I hope not" when I asked him for the presence of `++` in a language that was new to me. After >20 years I am starting to understand what he meant ;)